# ssh-keygen error: "Bits has bad value" creating a new ssh key for Git

Tags: git, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I'm trying to set a new SSH key for git using this command (in git bash)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b -C myemail@email.com
```

but it's returning `"Bits has bad value -C (invalid)"`

Tried googling and searching here, can't find similar problems. There were some but not specifically relating to git.

Answer (score 0):

turns out I was missing out the 4 digit number (is it the port number?) that comes after -b

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Comment: No; that's the number of bits in the key.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a numeric value for number of bits:

> -**b bits** 
>   Specifies the number of bits in the key to create. The minimum bit
>   length is 768 bits and the default length is 2048 bits.

`b` is the number of security bits to be applied in the rsa algorithm

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for noting. I've updated with something more recent.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
 ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -C "<your email_id>"
```

Here the -o stands for openSSH

Then open the csv file in the directory

```
     C:\Users\<your_user>\.ssh
```

copy the full value and paste in Github.
Bingo!!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing my prior *`rsa`* with **`ed25519`**, for the **`-t` option**, solved me.

*Solves*:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C your.email@youremaildomain.com
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
```

(the `cat` conveniently results with the generated key already copied to you clipboard, to then directly proceed with pasting to wherever you need [ex: https://github.com/settings/keys])

Prior attempt got `Bits has bad value ?\2404096 (invalid)`:

ssh-keygen -t **rsa** -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C your.email@youremaildomain.com

Comment: (can see related https://serverfault.com/questions/1080861/no-such-file-or-directory-when-trying-to-create-ssh-keys#comment1506403_1103120)